# Draw Line in jQplot with Sequence?

Tags: jqplot

Right now jqplot draw line from left to right, but I want to draw line by specifying points e.g.

Data: 
x-axis - 15, 10, 5, 25
y-axis - 10, 20, 30, 50

I want line start from 5 to 10 to 15 to 25 rather than from left to right.

appreciate help.

Comment: You want to specify point pairs?  `$.jqplot('chart1', [[[3,1],[2,2],[1,3]]]);`

Comment: yes, line would start from [1,3] -> [2,2] then [3,1]